# Alternating summation without for-loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math

I want to create the following vector in MATLAB without using a for-loop. I'm looking for a simple and elegant solution without all kinds of if statements.

`[x,y, (x+y)+x, ((x+y)+x)+y, (((x+y)+x)+y)+x]`

Comment: I assume for N rows, not only 4, right? Why not a for loop? it seems like the easiest way, and its probably very very fast anyway

Comment: @AnderBiguri N rows indeed. Because I can do it in a for loop and I want to be able to do it without one as well

Comment: Should the second entry not be `x+y`? Then entry `n` is `floor((n+1)/2)*x+floor(n/2)*y`.

Comment: @LutzL nope it's just y ;)

Comment: Ok, then set afterwards `seq[2]=y` to break the pattern in the demanded way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vector multiplication:

```
% x, y values
x = 3;
y = 1;
% number of repetitions
n = 2;
% generate times vector for x
timesx = repmat(1:n,[2 1]);
timesx = [timesx(:);n+1];
timesx(2) = 0;
% generate times vector for y
timesy = repmat(1:n,[2 1]);
timesy = [0;timesy(:)];
% sum
s = x*timesx + y*timesy;
```

and you get:

```
s = 
    [3     1     7     8    11]
```

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB >2015a

```
x=3;
y=1;
N=7;

rept=repelem(1:N,2);
res=[x,y,x*rept(3:3+N-3)+y*rept(2:2+N-3)]
```

There is maybe a way of adding that `repelem` inside the `res` line but I do not have MATLAB 2015a or bigger and I can not test this further.

Answer (score 0):

Codegolfing in MATLAB? 39 chars (courtesy to Luis Mendo, introducing `t`):

```
x=3;y=1;n=7;
t=(1:n)/2;f=ceil(t)*x+floor(t)*y;f(2)=y
```

Comment: Your code gives a dimension error. It should be something like `t = (1:N*2)/2; f = ceil(t)*x + floor(t)*y`